# Yii RBAC get all operations attached to specified role?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

i am using Yii Framework in order to develop a web application. i am hitting the wall when trying to get all the operations related to a specific role.

as an example, assume that there is user assigned as an Admin, which has some operations attached to the Admin. this Admin role inherits Moderator and User roles. both Moderator and User roles have some distinct operations. then how can we retrieve all user's operation which is coming from Admin, Moderator and User roles,.?

i have been looking at all those class references, none says that this is (im)possible. any idea,.?

thanks,.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with the default user management of Yii because nothing is saved in a DB. Use this extension for your RBAC http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user-management/ and it can be done easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be possible with a recursive function which calls `getItemChildren()`, see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/IAuthManager#getItemChildren-detail

As mentioned by Örs, there are extensions with GUI which do this already, besides yii-user-management, there is yii-rights and auth.

Comment: yes, i am still trying to recursively doing this. i am just dreaming if there is a predefined method or mechanism to do this,. thanks, schmunk,.!

Comment: A Google search with `getItemChildren recursive yii` brought this one up http://www.brokenbungee.com/blog/post/view/id/5/title/Finding+Inherited+Permissions+in+CDbAuthManager

Comment: i have done it, i just don't differ their type. thanks for the link. :)